# need help for url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

hello all i just want to rewrite my url for new site.

as you can see i had done it here but there you can see numbers that is id that is automtically generated .

http://www.domainname.com/sndslnf-1412.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]*)$ details.php?pid=$2 [L]

now i'm trying to just show the title no numbers 
ex: http://www.domainname.com/sndslnf

can anyone guide i have tried many time but don't know i always get and error .
"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

here is the htaccess code to 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be impossible. You have to change the functioning of your system.

To begin, use this htaccess code :

```
RewriteRule ^(a-z)+$ details.php?pid=$1
```

Now, the pid parameter is a string rather than a number. Then, you just have to check if this string is in your database, to display the string and informations who correspond to it.

I'm sorry for my bad english and i hope you understand me.